# Delete Product after Order

Tags: magento, product

I need to delete ordered Products programmatically after a Users Order is finished.

Some Ideas at which point I can hook in to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) for how to set up observers (you'll need to create your own module for this).

The event you want to listen for is `sales_order_place_after`, and when you declare an observer for it, your code will be called after any order is placed.

and you can add this code to your observer

To delete a product In magento use the following code.

This code will help to delete the product

```
<?php
Mage::register("isSecureArea", 1);
$product_id = 2; //use your own product id
try{
    Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load( $product_id  )->delete();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Delete failed";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event/observer method of magento to do something after order is placed.

you can use this event `sales_order_place_after`

Just create one module to listen magento observer/event.

In your /app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
        ...
        <frontend>
            ...
            <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <unique_event_name>
                            <class>{{modulename}}/observer</class>
                            <method>your function name</method>
                        </unique_event_name>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after>
            </events>
            ...
        </frontend>
        ...
    </config>
```

And then create an Observer class at /app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/Model/Observer.php

```
    class <namespace>_<modulename>_Model_Observer
   {
      public function your function name(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
      {
           $items =  $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getAllItems(); // you can get order item and then put delete function
      }

   }
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer.

I did it as you said - i created the Observer.php and Config.xml and put them into the right directions.

But nothing happens ? Do i just need to upload the files and thats it?

Comment: Have your module properly executed?

Comment: I set it up as you said it but I´m new with this... am I missing something?